# MongoDB cannot update values

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to convert certain fields in my records if there values are null. I'm now able to return those records with null values, but I'm unsure on how to update each record. This is my code(Python + pyMongo):

```
from geopy import geocoders, distance
from pymongo import Connection
import time

db=Connection().blah
coll = db.tweet_info

cursor = coll.find(
                {"$and": [
                            {"coordinates": {"$type":10}}, 
                            {"place": {"$ne": None}}
                    ]}, 
            {"coordinates": 1, "place": 1, "time_normal": 1, "_id":1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)

g = geocoders.Google()

while cursor.alive:
    counter=0
    try:
        doc = cursor.next()
        your_id = doc['_id']
        if not doc['coordinates']:
            counter+=1
            print doc  
            placeName = doc['place']['full_name']
            loc = g.geocode(placeName)
            coll.update({"_id" : your_id},{"$set": {"coordinates": loc}})             
            time.sleep(0.15)                        
        else: 
            pass

    except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
        pass

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: I get a: TypeError: update() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given). I also want to make sure that the code will update the specific record as it iterates through the entire collection. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have an update you need to have, what document to update, and what to update the actual fields to:

```
coll.update({... find ...},
{... update to ...}
)
```

To have an update you need to specify what document you want to be updated, so first you have to get the `_id`:

`"_id": 1,` // append this here: `{"coordinates": 1, "place": 1, "time_normal": 1}`

Then in the while you must get from the cursor the `_id` and the final update should look like this:

```
coll.update({"_id" : your_id}, // 
    {"$set": {"coordinates": loc}}
    )
```

(Just realised after your comment)

Comment: Thanks,  I tried that (see my edit in the original code) but it still doesn't update the collections with the new values.

Comment: oh no, not like that for the update, you need to input the actual id object. Consider adding `your_id = doc['_id']`, you have to atribute the `_id` you found to a variable and then .... trying again.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that. But it is still not updating these values in the collection.

Comment: could you edit your answer and add the full code with the changes so far.

Comment: try to print `your_id` to see it's value

Comment: The values of your_id are changing their values as the while loop is ececuted